# How to convert string to int to string again efficiently ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I may be walking a thin line with what constitutes a valid SO question here but...

What is the best way to convert a string to an int, add some value, then back to a string, in ruby?

```
(string.to_i+1).to_s
```

feels wrong and ugly.

EDIT:

After reading the various comments below, I'm going to leave this as-is without selecting an answer per-se as most of you say my solution above is the right way.  I guess Ruby has spoiled me into thinking there is always a simpler, better way (not a bad thing that we're looking for such a simpler solution, is it?)

My example lead to some submissions about .next, and my actual use case is not to just increment, I'm converting AM/PM time strings into 24-hour time, so actually I need to take something like 07:00 PM or 7p or 7 pM or anything like that and convert it to 19:00

I have that working just fine, I was just looking for something even more elegant.  I know SO is for "how" questions and stack review is for code review, I sort of cheated a bit here... sorry mods.

Comment: How is that wrong and ugly? Can you give an example an example of a *prettier* solution to that in another language?

Comment: This is how it should be done. Suppose the string is "123cat" or "-123" and you want to add 3. Can you think of a better way to obtain "126" or `-120` than what you proposed?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do exactly as in your example(incrementing), you can use a [`next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-next) method:

```
=> "1".next
=> "2"
```

Comment: `"-3".next #=> "-4"`. `"123cat".next #=> "123cau"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yep, _The successor is calculated by incrementing characters starting from the **rightmost** alphanumeric (or the rightmost character if there are no alphanumerics) in the string._

Comment: What is a realistic practical use of this method? It is not used for increment numbers only I guess.

Comment: not only numbers, letters too, `>> "a".next => "b"`, it's very usefull, i use it in own dynamic template engine.

Comment: Yes, `String#next` can be handy in all sorts of applications. But it should not be used here. Here's a another problem. If the string is `str` and you want to add `n = 1_000_000_000`, you need `n.times { str.next! }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String(Integer(string) + n)
```

`#to_s` and `#to_i` can be too permissive. Using `String` and `Integer` **functions** can avoid unexpected bugs.

Examples:

```
"$10".to_i 
#=> 0 
Integer("$10") 
#=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "$10"
"10.5".to_i 
#=> 10 
Integer("10.5") 
#=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "10.5"
```

Comment: `Integer()` raise an error if has invalid value. `Integer("b") => ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "b"`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can :)

```
eval("#{string} + #{number}").to_s
(Integer(string) + number).to_s
"#{string.to_i + number}"
"#{Integer(string) + number}"
etc...
```

First answer is more elegant any way.

Comment: Recommend `eval` can lead people make huge mistake.

Comment: An important use of `to_i` is with strings that begin with digits (and maybe a minus sign), followed by non-digits. `Integer(string)` will of course raise an exception in such cases. As a general comment, I suggest you avoid `"etc."`, `"..."`, etc. in answers (but OK in comments like this one :-]). I do agree that the first answer is more elegant (though incorrect).